create movement speed from x,y pixel coordinates
I have a dataset which is tracking a moving object. For each frame of the video (around 2,000 per video), it has an x pixel and a y pixel value (1920 x 1080p). I want to:
a) create a new column (xy) which has a spatial correlate of where that pixel is on the grid (each pixel/value on the grid should have its own unique coordinate)
b) create a speed of travel (aka the distance travelled between two frames), using something like the lag function.
I am unsure how best to create the xy column, as the data is a video, and does not relate to actual spatial data like real world coordinates.
Example of the data:



Frame
X
Y




1
5
1


2
3
4



I tried converting the coords using st_point and sf_as_sf but neither really work as they are more in line with real life coords.
